# Можно ли реализовать наследование изящнее?

Tags: c#, .net, архитектура

Есть некоторый базовый класс:

`DbDictionaryBase`, который хранит в себе поля.

Наследники данного класса дополняют его специфическими методами доступа к словарным данным, например какой-то конкретный словарь может иметь такие методы `GetNameById`,`GetFamById` и прочее.

Есть базовый ConverterBase, который так же хранит в несколько общий для наследников методов и поля, в том числе 1 из полей типа `DbDictionaryBase`.
Каждый конкретный Converter содержит в себе конкретный Dictionary и в итоге у меня все выглядит так:

```
class DbDictionaryBase
{
   OleDbConnection _db;
}

class DbDictionaryBase
{
   DbDictionaryBase _dict;
}

class ConcreateDictionary1:DbDictionaryBase
{
  string GetNameById(int id){}
  string GetFamById(int id){}
}

class ConcreateDictionary2:DbDictionaryBase
    {
      string GetCarNumberById(int id){}
    }

class ConcreateConverter1:ConverterBase
{
 ConcreateDictionary1 _dict
 ConcreateConverter1()
 {
   _dict=(ConcreateDictionary1)base.Dict
 }
//какая-то работа
void DoWork()
 {
   var t=_dict.GetNameById(123)
 }
    }
```

Как-то глаза мозолит и кажется, что можно сделать изящнее. Да, можно из базового класса вообще убрать `DbDictionaryBase` и каждой реализации ConverterBase присвоить конкретный словарь, но опять же чувствуется, что что-то не то...

Можно ли сделать красивее?

Comment: словами ничего не понятно, покажите код

Comment: @tym32167, я дополнил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, вам подойдёт такая иерархия классов. Если репозитории выстроены так:

```
class DbDictionaryBase
{
}

class NameDictionary : DbDictionaryBase
{
    public string GetNameById(string id) => default;
    public string GetSurnameById(string id) => default;
}

class EmployeeDictionary : NameDictionary
{
    public decimal GetSalaryById(string id) => default;
}
```

то конверторы выстроим так:

```
interface IConverter
{
    string Convert(string id);
}

abstract class ConverterBase<T> : IConverter where T : DbDictionaryBase
{
    protected T dict;
    public abstract string Convert(string id);
}
```

```
class NameConverter<T> : ConverterBase<T> where T : NameDictionary
{
    public override string Convert(string id) =>
        $"{dict.GetNameById(id)} {dict.GetSurnameById(id)}";
}

sealed class NameConverter : NameConverter<NameDictionary> { }
```

```
class EmployeeConverter<T> : NameConverter<T> where T : EmployeeDictionary
{
    public override string Convert(string id) =>
        $"{base.Convert(id)} (salary: {dict.GetSalaryById(id)})";
}

sealed class EmployeeConverter : EmployeeConverter<EmployeeDictionary> { }
```

То есть, как вы видите, всё время определяется два класса: один для расширения, и один для использования.

Comment: Да, думаю с Generic'ами красиво получится.

Answer (score 0):

У вас произойдет ошибка в строке `_dict=(ConcreateDictionary1)base.Dict` так как Dict не является ConcreateDictionary1 или его наследником. Если конечно эти классы не реализуют explicit операторы, что в принципе тут не нужно.

Вы можете описать generic класс

```
public class ConverterBase<TDictionary> where TDictionary : new()
{
    protected TDictionary Dictionary { get; } = new TDictionary();
}
```

И использовать его

```
public class ConcreteDictionary
{
    public string GetNameById(int id) => "Какое-то имя";
}

public class ConcreteConverter : ConverterBase<ConcreteDictionary>
{
    public string GetNameById(int id) => Dictionary.GetNameById(id);
}
```